# maximum size of parameters to system call

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system

I'm trying to implement a new system call in Linux kernel?

Is there a maximum size of the data passed as parameter to the system call?

For instance, one argument is a char pointer, but I noticed that if I allocate large (tens of KB) to that char array, the kernel crashes.

If there is a limit, what are the ways out? shared memory (but how)?

Comment: You actual question is "what did I do wrong?", and this cannot be answered without the code.

Comment: It's best if you are specific about whic syscall you are exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass more than 6 parameters to a syscall.

If you want you can give a pointer and access to the pointed area from the kernel but take care to use the right functions to do this, like the one in uaccess.h (copy_to/from_user ...) or use mapping or asynchronous IO.